# I create a project nextjs but it doesn't show the Home page but it shows the 404 page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

recently I got error when I create project with Nextjs everytime I run  `npm run dev` it shows 404 page

next version: 13.4.19

folders structure

[image]

package

```
{
  "name": "khuongviettai",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.5.1",
    "@types/react": "18.2.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "eslint": "8.47.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.19",
    "next": "13.4.19",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "^3.0.2"
  }
}
```

code Navbar and  subNavbar

```
import '../styles/css/globals.css';
import '../styles/css/variables.css';
import '../styles/css/fonts.css';
import type { Metadata } from 'next';

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import './navbar.css';

export interface INavbar {}

const Navbar: React.FunctionComponent<INavbar> = () => {
  return <header className="navbar">dhfghg</header>;
};

export default Navbar;
```

```
'use client';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './sub-navbar.css';


export interface ISubNavbar {}

const SubNavbar: React.FunctionComponent<ISubNavbar> = () => {
  return (
    <header className="sub-navbar">
      <div className="container">dfjhg</div>
    </header>
  );
};

export default SubNavbar;
```

image page

[image]